# No terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field - dates

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

**I have the following data:**

```
G_ID;"KID";"MG_DATE";"SQTY"
5697877;"1301633";"06/04/2012";"1"
5844541;"1301633";"03/04/2012";"1"
5826002;"1301633";"03/04/2012";"1"
```

When i try to load it with SQL*Loader I get the following error:

> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "X"."SALES", column SALE_DATE.
>   no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field

The CTL file:

```
OPTIONS ( SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE ...
BADFILE ...
DISCARDFILE ...
INTO TABLE "X"."SALES"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(ITEM_CODE integer,
LOC_CODE integer,
SALE_DATE date "dd/mm/yyyy",
QUANTITY integer)
```

Please help me understand what's wrong, the data is pretty simple and there are no special characters as it seems.

Comment: You should provide `x.sales` table description, too.

Comment: ITEM_CODE  INTEGER                            NOT NULL,  
  LOC_CODE   INTEGER                            NOT NULL,  
  SALE_DATE  DATE                               NOT NULL,  
  QUANTITY   INTEGER

Comment: @user3819249 Please don't add additional information in comments - edit your question instead (using the *edit* button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified the control file and succeeded the loading.

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'sales.dat'
INTO TABLE "X"."SALES"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ITEM_CODE,
LOC_CODE,
SALE_DATE date "dd/mm/yyyy",
QUANTITY)
```

I think you don't need to specify the data type `integer` in the control file, since the table's column type is `number` it will automatically convert the data to number.

When you specified the data type `integer`, it seems that `sqlldr` treats the column length in the data file as 4, which leads to error.

If you want to specify the data type, then use `integer external` instead of `integer` only, like this:

```
...
ITEM_CODE integer external,
LOC_CODE integer external,
SALE_DATE date "dd/mm/yyyy",
QUANTITY integer external)
```